# How do I parse the NULL value?

Tags: plsql

I have a PIPE delimited file ( 3 pipes) which also has Null values. How do I pull the data including the NULL value from this example?

```
with data as

( select 'Abc|||KXG||||||CCC|||5/12/2014 12:12:22,DDD,EEE,FFF' str from dual)

select REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '([^|||]*)||| |$', 1, 3, NULL, 1 )  from data;
```

Comment: How standard is PL/SQL regex?

Answer (score 0):

If you prepend `|||`, then could you use

```
((|||)([^|]*)){5}
```

And capture each 3rd group?

Comment: plz - use your suggestion with my example and show me how to pull the  third value which is null, from the string? i tried your code , and it did not work..

Comment: I asked you how standard `PL/SQL` regex is. You did not answer. I don't know `PL/SQL`, but I know regex. Regex's normally have something called a "capturing group." The values of those groups can be extracted and used in sequence. I know how to do that in `Java`, in `Vi`, and with Unix power tools. If `PL/SQL` is standard, it will have some way to do it.

Comment: Yes, It is very standard and used very often. I am using PLSQL for this task. I looked up Capturing Group with REG_EXP ..but It was not the answer I was looking for... Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
  2    select 'Abc|||KXG||||||CCC|||5/12/2014 12:12:22,DDD,EEE,FFF' from dual
  3  )
  4  select COLUMN_VALUE field_nbr, REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,'(.*?)(\|\|\||$)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS match_value
  5        FROM   tbl,
  6               TABLE(
  7                 CAST(
  8                   MULTISET(
  9                     SELECT LEVEL
 10                     FROM   DUAL
 11                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( str ,'\|\|\|' )+1
 12                   ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
 13                 )
 14               );

 FIELD_NBR MATCH_VALUE
---------- ---------------------------------------------------
         1 Abc
         2 KXG
         3
         4 CCC
         5 5/12/2014 12:12:22,DDD,EEE,FFF

SQL>
```